# How do I make my function for counting the amount of Integers in a string work?

Tags: c, string, function

So, I basically thought I had this small little program all figured out - I was trying to make a program with a function which looks at what the user has entered and counts how many integers are in what the user has entered, like so:

```
void finish(int a, char *b, int c);

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int numb=0;
    char phrase[30];

    printf("This program will count the amount of \nnumbers in an entered phrase.\n");
    printf("Please enter your phrase: ");
    gets(phrase);
    finish(i, phrase, numb);
}

void finish(int a, char *b, int c)
{
    while(b[a]!='\0'){
        if(isdigit(b[a])==1){
                c++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    printf("\nThe phrase you entered has %i numbers",a);
}
```

Technically, the program works - but it counts everything entered as an integer - for example, typing in `"hello44"` is registered as 6 numbers instead of only 2.

A similar program I made has no issues correctly registering the same phrase as only including 2 numbers, so what is my problem here, and how could I solve it while still using a function?

Comment: Please also note that `isdigit()` is not required to return `1` on success, only that it is not `0`.

Comment: regarding the function: `gets()` That function has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the C language since (approx) 2009.  Suggest using `fgets()` (which has a different parameter list)

Comment: regarding: `if(isdigit(b[a])==1){`  This is an incorrect usage of the `isdigit()`.  Suggest: `if( isdigit(b[a]) ){`

Comment: regarding: `finish(i, phrase, numb);` and  `void finish(int a, char *b, int c)`  The variable `numb` in main()` can only be updated if the address of `numb` is passed.  Therefore the two statements should be:  `finish(i, phrase, &numb);` and  `void finish(int a, char *b, int *c)`.  then when updating the value, rather than `c++;`  use `(*c)++;`  similar consideration exist for the first parameter to `finish()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your count variable is c, but you print your loop variable a.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
printf("\nThe phrase you entered has %i numbers",a);
```

there is outputted the variable `a` instead of the variable `c`. There should be

```
printf("\nThe phrase you entered has %i numbers",c);
```

Also the condition in the if statement

```
f(isdigit(b[a])==1){
```

is incorrect. It is not necessary that if a given character is a digit then the function will return exactly `1`. It can return any non-zero value.

The first and third function parameters are redundant. The function should do only one thing count the number of digits in a string.

Also the function `gets` is not a standard C function any more. It is unsafe. Instead use the standard function `fgets`.

The function and the program in whole can look the following way.following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t finish( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        n += isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) != 0;
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 30 };
    char phrase[N];

    printf( "This program will count the amount of\n"
            "numbers in an entered phrase.\n" );

    printf( "Please enter your phrase: " );

    fgets( phrase, sizeof( phrase ), stdin );

    printf( "\nThe phrase you entered has %zu numbers", finish( phrase ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
This program will count the amount of
numbers in an entered phrase.
Please enter your phrase: hello44
The phrase you entered has 2 numbers
```

Comment: regarding; `n += isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) != 0;`  This is missing a needed set of parens.  It should be: `n += (isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) != 0);`

Comment: My compiler, gcc, told me that it is missing the set of parens

Comment: @user3629249 Change the compiler!:) The expression is totally correct.